# WPF Datagrid column auto width broken

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, autosize, datagridcolumn

I have an DataGrid with ColumnWidth="*" and then application will started i see this:
[1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLL90.png)

I maximize window and all good:

[2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXcDW.png)

But. When i minimize my window, i see minimize columns:

[3rd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEDNL.png)

My maximize and minimize function:

```
private void MaxButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e != null)
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            if (CustomMaximized)
            {
                TopResizeRectangles.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                DownResizeRectangles.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                CustomMaximized = false;
                Width = NormalWidth;
                Height = NormalHeight;
                //Left = NormalLeft;
                //Top = NormalTop;

                MaxButton.Style = Resources["Maximize"] as Style;
            }
            else
            {
                NormalWidth = Width;
                NormalHeight = Height;
                NormalLeft = Left;
                NormalTop = Top;

                TopResizeRectangles.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                DownResizeRectangles.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

                CustomMaximized = true;
                Width = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
                Height = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
                Left = 0;
                Top = 0;

                MaxButton.Style = Resources["Minimize"] as Style;
            }
        }
    }
```

And when window size change i make this:

```
private void Page_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var column in VisualisationScoreboardGrid.Columns)
            column.Width = 0;

        VisualisationScoreboardGrid.UpdateLayout();

        foreach (var column in VisualisationScoreboardGrid.Columns)
            column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);

        VisualisationScoreboardGrid.UpdateLayout();
    }
```

I use a custom solution because using just xaml ColumnWidth="*" under certain conditions gives a similar result to the above. How a make normal auto width for my columns?

Comment: You don't need to control the column width. Use the values of fractions, for example Width="1*" Width="2.2*". This is a standard way and it works well. What are your problems with this?

Comment: @alexander-shapovalov, I tried a simple Width="*", but the problem is extraordinary. The application is located on a server where the screen has a low response and at certain moments the collapse of the window leads to the collapse of the columns to the minimum size, this surprised me and I began to look for a solution, but I did not find anything, I decided to write here. Now I have made a crutch, when opening the form I set MinWidth = ActualWidth and then when collapsing the columns remain readable.